# Terminal not reading a for-loop statement

Tags: c++

I have failed many times when executing a code, I thought it was in my logic in how I use loop statements, but when I tried this code:

```
int main(){
    cout << "yo \n";
    for(int i; i < 5; i++){
        cout << "meh \n";
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output:

```
    yo
    meh
    meh
    meh
    meh
    meh
```

But in my disappointment, it only showed

```
    yo
```

So, what's the problem with this simple block of code?

Comment: You didn't initialize `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `i` is uninitialized. Initialize the `i` value, Like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

`uninitialized` variables to hold **garbage** data.So, this is **undefined behaviour**.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing many times because it is undefined behaviour to use uninitialized variable i. Any thing can happen in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the value of **i**.**i++** is trying to increment an uninitialised variable.